# How to send an email with inline images using zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, email, inline-images

The documentation specifies how to add inline attachement, but what is the correct way of referencing it from the html part? Is it possible to include images automatically as it is in other libraries?

Maybe someone has written a little snippet and is willing to share?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not exactly a trivial thing, lucky for you someone has subclassed Zend_Mail (`Demo_Zend_Mail_InlineImages`) to do that, see here:

http://davidnussio.wordpress.com/2008/09/21/inline-images-into-html-email-with-zend-framework/

Comment: Here's another example: https://gist.github.com/3415630 (The link above is only for local file:/// images)

Answer (score 2):

i write wrapper for mail class

```
private function _processHtmlBody($I_html, $I_mailer, $I_data) {

$html = $I_html;
$mail = $I_mailer;

$xmlBody = new DomDocument();
$xmlBody->loadHTML($html);

$imgs = $xmlBody->getElementsByTagName('img');
$I_data['atts'] = array();

$imgCount = 0;
foreach ($imgs as $img) {   
  $imgCount++;
  $imgUrlRel = $img->getAttribute('src');

  $imgId = sha1(time() . $imgCount . $imgUrlRel);
  $html = str_replace($imgUrlRel, 'cid:' . $imgId, $html);

  $imgUrlFull = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $imgUrlRel;

  $imgBinary = file_get_contents($imgUrlFull);

  $imgPart = $mail->createAttachment($imgBinary);

  $imgPart->filename    = 'image' . $imgCount . '.jpg';
  $imgPart->id = $imgId;

  $I_data['atts'][] = $imgPart;
  }
  $mail->setBodyHtml($html);

  return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending Zend_Mail you can directly embed your image in base64 using html.

Here is an example image that I included in my email template:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?= base64_encode(file_get_contents("/local/path/to/image.png")) ?>" />
```